# SQL Server / ODBC scrollable result set performance

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I've got an application connecting to a SQL Server database via ODBC, and providing query functionality through a Web interface. In order to map the database onto our web framework, I am using a scrollable result set. Most of the rest of the application uses a forward-only cursor.

I've got an order table with a huge number of rows, and a query:

```
SELECT * FROM order
```

If I run this with my own command line program, it immediately starts returning data. If I only fetch 25 rows, the query runs very quickly. If I run it on the web screens, the query times out after 30 seconds, without returning any data.

Both methods go through the same sequence of calls, except for the cursor type. In the command line program, I use `SQLSetStmtAttr` to set `SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE` to `SQL_CURSOR_FORWARD_ONLY`, while in the web version, I use `SQL_CURSOR_DYNAMIC`.

I've gone in with the debugger to find out where the delay is, and what I've seen is the `SQLExecute` call takes around 50 seconds with the cursor set to dynamic. For info, I was using `SQL_CURSOR_STATIC` before, and `SQL_CURSOR_DYNAMIC` is my first attempt to fix the problem.

Is there any way to get a performant scrollable result set in SQL Server via ODBC?

Answer (score 1):

Scrollable cursors are seriously a no no no on sql server regardless what API you use - and ODBC makes them ahrder. Get around them pretty much at any cost.

Comment: The problem is that some of the features of the interface require returning to a previous row number.  It would be a fairly substantial redesign to remove or re-work these features - the interface wasn't really designed for SQL Server.